# how does keytool know which CA to use

Tags: java, keytool

The server has changed from http to https. Instead of modifying client code (of course the host which was http is now https), we use keytool to save server CA. When I used keytool, I see a list of all stored CA (about 100 pieces).

So how does JRE know which CA to use? And what is the story behind this, like why when JRE is configured with a CA the client code could remain the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer the basic questions you pose.
Java and Keytool know which CAs to trust by consulting a special file named *cacerts* which is shipped with the JRE and it's placed in `<JRE_HOME>/lib/security`.

This kind of file is usually called KeyStore or TrustStore.

This file is shipped **by default** by the "creator" of the JRE (e.g. Oracle) and contains  list of Certificate Authority certificates to be trusted (usually updated at every release).

It's not that different from the same process for browsers.

As for the story behind this, if I understand correctly, we are talking about PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) which, in you case, very roughly, means that when **your** JRE keystore gets updated with the new CA certificate, then entities (such as SSL Sites, applets,etc) presenting a certificate provided (usually sold) by that CA are now basically valid and trusted, since now a trusted third party (the new CA) can guarantee (by means of encryption and digital signature) that "you are effectively you" in a digital scenario.

Also worth noting that, Keytool can be instructed to use a user-defined keystore with the `-keystore <keystore_path>` command line option (and even the JVM can configure a specific non-default truststore for SSL connection via a system property like this)